# Extracting data from SAP ERP into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sap-erp, sap-hr

I am extracting from SAP ERP into SQL Server using a commercial SSIS connector which has been working fine.

But when I extract a certain table some data disappears. For example I run the following query on the target table.

```
SELECT * FROM PA0001
WHERE PERNR = '12345678'
```

I get no results, but PERNR 12345678 is in the source table.

Row counts match on the source and target table. So the data should be there.

Has anyone had this issue before? Any tips on how to find the missing row?

Comment: i'm guessing this column contains some invisible chars which makes 12345678 not match it. Did  you try: `PERNR LIKE '%12345678%'`

Comment: Yes tried LIKE. The source field is string with a 8 character length.

Comment: In SAP ERP, `PA0001.PERNR` is internally eight numeric characters but the SAP ERP display removes the leading zeroes, so if you see `1234`, you should query `00001234`. EDIT: to troubleshoot, if you are limited to 8 characters, use `PERNR LIKE '%123456%' AND PERNR LIKE '%345678%'`.

Comment: Tried the leading zeros but the PERNR number is 8 characters longs, I've tried LIKE '%1234% %01234% just about every combination to match any of the string but still nothing.

Comment: ok, can you use some other Column/ID to find the row in both tables? Otherwise i don't know, this is impossible to debug. Are there any rows in target where PERNR <> ''? It could be you're connecting to wrong table/database/server/network/work place. Also, what's the datatype of PERNR in target? Perhaps it becomes NULL due to truncation errors

Comment: Agreed, this is a question impossible to answer as long as you don't first refine at your side.

Comment: 1. Modify the package locally. Either add a filter/where clause to only pull back 12345678 from the source system OR add a Conditional Split and filter against PENR there. Do you see the row from the source system show up? Does it land in the target table? Any warnings fired in the package?

Comment: 2. If that works as expected, then it's something specific to production. For that, you'll want to add a [Data Tap](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/13/ssis-data-taps/) to your next SSIS package execution (assumes Project Deployment Model) and then investigate the resulting CSV. Depending on cost (dealing with DBAs, run time, set up, etc), I'd look at adding 2 taps: One immediately after the source component and one immediately preceding the destination component. Is 12345678 in both?